# Sending an Email through Firebase WebApp

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my project idea is a school attendance system, and I want to send an email to all students in a specific class.

my question is there a way to send an email using the (noReply@firebase.com) email that is dedicated for every firebase project or do I have to use a thirdparty like Gmail of Outlook or is there some other way?

Comment: I'm not sure of an answer to your question but it may be worth taking a look at Mailgun https://www.mailgun.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use a third party API for mailing,because it don't think that 'noReply@firebase.com' allows us to broadcast an email.

Answer (score 0):

You should add information on how you want to send those emails. Is it in a firebase webapp, nodejs, java...

The short answer is you should read on the SMTP protocol which is the protocol in which emails are sent on the web.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

You can actually send an emails with anyones domain, but gmail and outlook will verify if the sources are trustworthy.

Here is an example in Java on sending emails with SMTP with any domain name.

https://www.journaldev.com/2532/javamail-example-send-mail-in-java-smtp